# Remove leading zeros from numbers in string

Tags: c#, string, numbers, int

This is my string:

```
03930:03194:03888:04251:04218:03676:04048:03876:00000:00000:00000:00000:00000:00000:00000:00000
```

And I need to remove all leading zeroes and turn it into this:

```
3930:3194:3888:4251:4218:3676:4048:3876:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: string.TrimStart('0') could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should split the content, parse to `int`, call `ToString` on each of them and join together into `string` again:

```
var result = String.Join(":", source.Split(':').Select(x => int.Parse(x).ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex. I think it is more efficient than parsing each substring and shorter with one function call:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(sourse, "(^0+|(:)0*([1-9])|(:0)0*)", "$2$3$4");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `Split` the string and then trim the leading zeros with `TrimStart`:

```
string.Join(":", source.Split(":").Select(x => x.TrimStart('0')));
```

I think this would be a bit more efficient than parsing each substring.

Comment: This will remove single-zero numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can first call `Split` in order to turn the long string into an enumerable of strings, then you can parse them into numbers by using `int.Parse`, and then call `Join` to combine them back into a long string.